# Draw line drawn from point to an open infowindow?

Tags: carto

I want the infowindows on my map to be in a fixed location, but that sometimes makes it hard to tell which point was clicked (which point is associated with the infowindow displayed).
Is there a way to draw a line from the point to an opened infowindow located in a fixed position or make the selected point stand out from the rest of the non-selected points?

Answer (score 1):

Why not implement something like a hover effect?

http://bl.ocks.org/javisantana/8313604

Just leave your feature *highlighted* until the infowindow is closed